# I want to be like my father in the future. What would he be called?

Tags: word-choice

Not something like *inspiration* / *motivation*
There is a word for this, right? Thanks a lot for helping.. ^^

Comment: A role model. A good example to follow. An exemplar.

Answer (score 4):

The word you could be looking for might be *idol*, or possibly *role model*.

> **idol**: a person or thing that is greatly admired, loved, or revered.
>
> **role model**: a person looked to by others as an example to be imitated.

*Oxford Dictionary*

Answer (score 0):

*per* Mitch's fitting suggestion in comment,

**exemplar** *noun*: a person or thing serving as a typical example or ***excellent model***. See, Google [**exemplar**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=exemplar+synonyms&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=exemplar+synonyms&gs_l=hp..0.0.0.0.4.118041...........0.flPYZCYbGgg&gws_rd=ssl)